# Datamatrix in R - extracting data from scatterplot

Tags: r

I am trying to modify a R script but I have only basic experience with R:

question 1:
In line: `for (i in 1:nrow(x))`. what does the integer 1 actually do? Changing the value to 2 or higher seem to have a big effect on the output.

question 2:
I have been getting the message:

```
"Error in if (p[2] > a + b * p[1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

. In general, what might be causing this?

Any help is much appreciated!

---

question edited:

Say I have a dataframe for plotting scatterplot. The dataframe would be organized in the following fashion (in CSV format):

```
name ABC EFG
1    32  45
2    56  67
to, say 200 000 entries
```

I am going to first do a scatterplot, after which I am going to subset a portion of the dataset into A using alphahull and export them as XYZ. The script for doing this:

```
#plot first plot containing all data
plot(x = X$ABC,
y = X$EFG,
pch=20,
)

#subset data using ahull. choose 4 points on the plot
A <- ahull(locator(4, type="p", pch=20), alpha=10000) 

#exporting subset
XYZ <- {}
for (i in 1:nrow(X)) { if (inahull(A, c(X$ABC[i],X$EFG[i]))) XYZ <- rbind(X,X[i,])}
```

I am getting the following message if the number of data points in the subset that I choose is too large:Error in if (p[2] > a + b * p[1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Please post the reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 - this is a for loop - it is executing once for each row in the matrix or data frame x (not sure what x is here exactly). Changing it to 2 will mean the loop happens one less time.  Without the rest of the code I can't say much else.

Question 2 - can you post the whole code? It apparently needs to evaluate that expression and one or more of the values is missing.

Comment: Basically the line is to extract a subset of data from X that was defined as A using inahull. ABC and EFG are the variables associated with X

Comment: I am not familiar with this package. I think the easiest step here is to just run the part in the if() for a couple (all) of rows to see if it gives a correct TRUE/FALSE value. What happens to the inahull function if there is a NA value in the second part?

Answer (score 0):

**Say you have data** `x`

```
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility

x<-as.data.frame(rnorm(10)) # generate random number and store it as dataframe

k<-2  #assign n as 2 
for (i in (1:nrow(x))){
cat("this is row",i,"\n")
show (k)
k<-k+i
}
show (k)
this is row 1 
[1] 2
this is row 2 
[1] 3
this is row 3 
[1] 5
this is row 4 
[1] 8
this is row 5 
[1] 12
this is row 6 
[1] 17
this is row 7 
[1] 23
this is row 8 
[1] 30
this is row 9 
[1] 38
this is row 10 
[1] 47
> show (k)
[1] 57
```